# How to verify the IV with the private key before mcrypt_decrypt php

Tags: php, encryption

I use the mcrypt_encrypt function and mcrypt_decrypt function to encrypt and decrypt some infomation. But some time I recieve the error:

```
Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): Received initialization vector of size 0, but size 32 is required for this encryption mode in
```

I want to know how I can verify the IV with the private key, if true call mcrypt_decrypt else return false. I use mode CBC.

Comment: Your question, as a whole, doesn't make a lot of sense.  You shouldn't be using your encryption key (I assume symmetric even though you use the term "private key") to determine if the IV is legitimate.  Instead, you should be using an HMAC with a **different** key to determine if the entire payload is legitimate.  Or even better, ditch CBC mode and use GCM.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding bugs dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret. Do not report any passing errors on decryption.